# CKeditor 5 does not load with Aggregate JavaScript files option

Tags: performance, css-js-aggregation

I use Drupal 9.5.5, CKeditor 5 and BootstrapBarrio theme.

When I enable "Aggregate JavaScript files" option in Performance, CKeditor does not load when a user (non admin) edits node.

I uninstalled Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation module also.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: What does the browser console log say?

Comment: Browser console log says:

Uncaught TypeError: t.widget is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: _ref is undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Drupal.editors is undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Drupal.ajax is not a function

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/upgrading-drupal/2022-12-22/ckeditor-5-stoped-working-after-an-update-to-drupal-95 describes a similar error, but there is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an error with JQuery UI library order

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3222107